# modifying xml attributes using Installshield

Tags: xml, installshield

I'm using installshield 2010. I'm trying to modify xml attributes related to connection string in installshield.
i have imported xml file and selected the elements which I need to modify.
i'm using function onSQLLogin after creating an sql connection to get username and password given by user.

The peculiar behaviour is that if I debug, then the xml attributes get updated.
If i test using "test release1" in build menu, file is not being updated.

Any ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

got the answer for my query. I have done all bits of correct, excepting that I was using "Test Release1" menu option expecting it to update the xmlfile. XML file is updated only if we "Run Release1" instead of "Test Release1".